# NameError: name 'ExceptionGroup' is not defined

Tags: python, exception

I work through Python tutorial and ran against a sample in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html in section **8.9. Raising and Handling Multiple Unrelated Exceptions** which doesn't work by me:

```
$ python
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> excs = [OSError('error 1'), SystemError('error 2')]
>>> raise ExceptionGroup('there were problems', excs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ExceptionGroup' is not defined
>>>
```

Why? Isn't a `ExceptionGroup` a built-in exception? The compiler doesn't give any errors and IDE pops up the documentation for this class...

The next thought was - I have to import something:

```
>>> from builtins import ExceptionGroup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'ExceptionGroup' from 'builtins' (unknown location)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-groups), ExceptionGroup was only added in Python 3.11. Make sure you check your Python version

Comment: Thanks. Didn't thought about it. I had an impression that such a class must have been existing in the builtins since a long time.